# Lagrange Multipliers with Integral and three constraints

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I have tried to solve the following problem with Lagrange multipliers, but I have trouble getting started.

I want to minimize $$F(\alpha) = \frac12\int_0^1 [u(x) - 1]^2\,dx$$ with the constraints $f(x) = -u''(x), \; u(0) = 0, \; u'(1) = \alpha$.

$u(x)$ is the solution of $\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2} = 0,$ so $u(x) = \alpha x$.

I don't know if I need this.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused about $f(x)=-u''(x).$ Is $f$ given? If so, what is it? Otherwise, can't you just minimize $\frac12 \int_0^1[\alpha x-1]^2\,dx?$

Answer (score 0):

Off-hand, I'd say you could just do
\begin{align*}\frac12\int_0^1[\alpha x-1]^2\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1[\alpha^2 x^2-2\alpha x+1]\,dx \\
&=\frac12\left[\frac{\alpha^2 x^3}{3}-\alpha x^2+x\right]_0^1 \\
&=\frac12\left[\frac{\alpha^2}{3}-\alpha+1\right].
\end{align*}
You can complete the square or take the derivative (I opt for the latter):
$$\frac{dF(\alpha)}{d\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{3}-\frac12\overset{\text{set}}{=}0\quad\implies\quad \alpha=\frac32\quad\implies\quad F(3/2)=\frac12\left[\frac34-\frac32+1\right]=\frac18.$$
But this completely ignores the condition $f(x)=-u''(x).$ For this condition to be consistent with your other conditions will require that $f(x)=0.$

Comment: Yes this is right, I did this indeed. You're also right when you say that f(x) = 0. 
This way however, doesn't use Lagrange Multipliers and that's what I can't figure out. 
I looked at paragraph 14.8 of the calculus book of James Stewart, and based on his method I am supposed to solve this with Lagrange Multipliers.. 
Any ideas how to?!